# Why is the psychrometric ratio of an air-water system assumed constant and equal to 1?

Tags: thermodynamics

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychrometrics#Psychrometric_ratio) defines the psychrometric ratio as the ratio between the convective transfer coefficient $h_c$ and the product of the convective mass transfer coefficient $k_y$ and the humid heat $c_s$:

$$\frac{h_c}{k_yc_s}$$

It claims that this happens to be numerically equal to $1$. However I would assume that both $h_c$ and $k_y$ are *not* constant and depend on air speed, air humidity, water and air temperature. The sources quoted in the article aren't very convincing.

Comment: Is this ratio at least dimensionless in terms of its units?

Comment: Yes, it is dimensionless. I wonder whether the assumption that it is close to 1 also comes with the assumption that it is almost constant - maybe it is indeed a non linear coefficient but if fluctuates slightly. I would assume $h_c$ and $k_c$ to be positively correlated.